# You don't have sufficient privileges to open lookup dialog box error in CRM Online 2016

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have exported a solution from one of my existing CRM Online instance, and imported to another new instance which is also CRM Online 2016.

The solution contains customized Opportunity entity (forms, views, fields, processes, etc), and a custom Security role.

The solution contains one custom field "Follow up Contact" which is of lookup type and referencing to Users entity.

After importing the solution, I have assigned one of the user to the custom security role in new instance.

Now, when I try to create a new opportunity, and try selecting "Follow up Contact", I am seeing no user in the list, whereas the associated view is expected to display at least 5 users. Also, when I try clicking on "Look for more records", I get following error -

"You do not have sufficient privileges to open this Lookup dialog box."

Whereas, users with same security role in the source solution can see the items in the "Follow up Contact" dropdown, and also that "Look for more records", work fine for them.

Any idea what could be the possible reason? Are there any changes in terms of security roles in latest upgrade of CRM Online?

Comment: Does it work for a System Administrator ? Also: can the same user query the data through advanced find ?

Comment: no, it doesn't work for a System Administrator as well. Also, the same user can successfully query data through advanced find. As well as, the view which is associated with the lookup field is also returning data. The problem is only with the lookup field, as it doesn't show up list and "Look for More records" link is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well strange things do happen!!

I opened the form in designer mode.. disabled the execution of the particular method which contains scripts for setting default value to the lookup control.

Published the solution.

Then again, enabled the script execution...

and to my surprise, the lookup field started working...

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and here is what worked for us.

We had a custom entity that was related to the out-of-the-box `Account` entity. We had 3 lookups on that custom entity to `Account`. Even with System Administrator role, none of our users could get any records to return from the lookup search and we got the error message specified in the title.

We ended up deleting ONE of the lookup fields (picked the one with least dependencies). We added that field and its dependencies back in. It was annoying manual process, but after this all THREE of our lookup fields were fixed.

I'm guessing the Account-Custom Entity relationship XML behind the scenes was corrupted somehow, and deleting/recreating cleaned it up.